# Is it possible to delete a specific column in a row from a table(in mysql database)?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, delete-row

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [first_name] => john
    [last_name] => miller
    [email] => johnmiller@gmail.com
    [phone] => +1000000
)
```

Now lets say i just want to delete "[email]". Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straightforward: `ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN columnname`.

Comment: You say you want to delete it in *a row*.  Do you mean remove the column from the table or just one row?

Comment: in just one row.

Comment: @MHZGAMER `UPDATE table set email = NULL where id=1`? How about that?

Comment: @Blackbam can you write a code about this if you don't mind.?

Comment: @MHZGAMER Do you want to delete the value from the array or from the table in the SQL database?

Comment: @Blackbam one "array" is holding complete data from one row.so i want to delete a single column in row.

Comment: `unset($array['email'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the syntax for ALTER TABLE Drop Column is,

`ALTER TABLE "table_name" DROP "column_name";`